# Windsor: Am I completely misunderstanding how child containers work?

Tags: castle-windsor

Can someone please explain why this test fails:

```
    [Fact]
    public void ResolveAllDoesNotReturnServicesRegisteredInParent()
    {
        // arrange
        var windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer();

        windsorContainer.Register(Component.For<IView>().ImplementedBy<ViewA>().LifeStyle.Transient);
        windsorContainer.Register(Component.For<IView>().ImplementedBy<ViewB>().LifeStyle.Transient);

        var childContainer = new WindsorContainer();

        windsorContainer.AddChildContainer(childContainer);

        // act
        IView[] views = childContainer.ResolveAll<IView>();

        // assert
        Assert.True(views.Length == 2);
    }
```

Comment: You might be interested in this:
http://kozmic.pl/archive/2010/06/02/castle-windsor-and-child-containers.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you resolve from parent will that succeed? Notice that ResolveAll will only resolve the components that are resolvable.

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing. I missed a dependency in the configuration.